# Create Reverse Proxy with parallel connection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reverse-proxy

I write this code for reverse proxy in C# ASP.net

```
 public class ProxyHandler : IHttpHandler, IRouteHandler
{
    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    DBEntities db = new DBEntities();

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string inputAction = context.Request.Url.ToString().Substring(context.Request.Url.ToString().IndexOf("/rp/") + 4);
        string action = inputAction.Substring(0, inputAction.IndexOf('/'));
        string input = inputAction.Substring(inputAction.IndexOf('/') + 1);
        if (action == "getFile")
        {
            string hash = input;
            var link = db.LinkDownloaders.Where(tbl => tbl.sourcePathMD5 == input).FirstOrDefault();
            if (link != null)
            {
                HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(link.sourcePath);
                
                webRequest.Proxy = null;

                webRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
               
                if (context.Request.Headers["Range"] != null)
                {
                    string range = context.Request.Headers["Range"].Replace("bytes=", ""); 
                    string[] ranges = range.Split('-');
                    long start = 0;
                    long end = 0;
                    long.TryParse(ranges[0], out start);
                    long.TryParse(ranges[1], out end);
                    if (end > start)
                    {
                        webRequest.AddRange(start, end);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        webRequest.AddRange("bytes", start);
                    }
                }
                webRequest.CachePolicy = new HttpRequestCachePolicy(HttpRequestCacheLevel.NoCacheNoStore);

                var response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();


                string fileName = response.ResponseUri.Segments.LastOrDefault();

                context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=\""+ fileName +"\"");
                foreach (string item in response.Headers.AllKeys)
                {
                    context.Response.AddHeader(item, response.Headers.Get(item));
                }
                Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                context.Response.ContentType = response.ContentType;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                while (true)
                {
                    int read = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    if (read <= 0)
                        return;
                    context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        return this;
    }


}
```

This code work well for download file with one connection (browser downloader) but when I using Internet download manager programs for download file as parallel connection or resume download that code doesn't work.
I know a little about http headers and I add "Range" header for get file parts but still doesn`t work.
please suggest and guided me.

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not a problem statement that we can assist with.

Comment: Why? "Doesn't work" ! My code work well with one download connection but  "Doesn't work" in parallel connection. What is wrong with my question? @IanKemp

Comment: @xwpedram "Doesn't work" is too broad and doesn't help us help you. What does that mean? Do you get an error? Which error? Which status code? Which response? etc... Read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Maybe my question is incomplete due to my poor English. Anyway, thank you for comment. I found the answer to my questions and put it for public use. @C.AugustoProiete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking response and request headers with fiddler, I find out partial http request status code is "206" not "200", then I just add this line code to my reverse proxy handler

```
context.Response.StatusCode = 206;
```